# Creating a new column in pandas quantile using Quantile function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, quantile

I want to create a column Quantile, for each date. Calculated the Quantile for each unique value Sales value. Ie Category always corresponds to the same number in sales for each particular date.

I have dataframe which is indexed by date. There are many dates and multiple of the same dates. Example of the subset of df for 1 day:

```
          Category  Sales   Ratio 1 Ratio 2
11/19/2016  Bar     300     0.46    0.96
11/19/2016  Bar     300     0.56    0.78
11/19/2016  Bar     300     0.43    0.96
11/19/2016  Bar     300     0.47    0.94
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.92    0.12
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.43    0.74
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.98    0.65
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.76    0.67
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.79    0.80
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.90    0.91
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.89    0.31
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.69    0.99
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.07    0.18
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.75    0.59
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.07    0.64
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.14    0.42
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.30    0.67
11/19/2016  Pub     250     0.64    0.09
11/19/2016  Pub     250     0.93    0.37
11/19/2016  Pub     250     0.69    0.42
```

I want a code which adds a new column called Quantile which calculates for each date the 0.5 quantile of unique Sales. Key thing to note is Sales is always the same for a category for a particular date (things change as dates change).

Example of a solution: df['Quantile'] = df.Sales.groupby(df.index).transform(lambda x: x.quantile(q=0.5, axis=0, interpolation='midpoint'))

However this would not suffice (even if it worked). For this example (for this one date), In the new column df['Quantile'], all values would be the same for a partcular date.

For this date the calculation would use 300, 550, 700 and 250 for the quantile.

Therefore the final df would look like this:

```
      Category  Sales   Ratio 1 Ratio 2     Quantile
11/19/2016  Bar     300     0.46    0.96      425
11/19/2016  Bar     300     0.56    0.78      425
11/19/2016  Bar     300     0.43    0.96      425
11/19/2016  Bar     300     0.47    0.94      425
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.92    0.12      425
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.43    0.74      425
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.98    0.65      425
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.76    0.67      425
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.79    0.80      425
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.90    0.91      425
11/19/2016  Casino  550     0.89    0.31      425
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.69    0.99      425
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.07    0.18      425
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.75    0.59      425
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.07    0.64      425
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.14    0.42      425
11/19/2016  Café    700     0.30    0.67      425
11/19/2016  Pub     250     0.64    0.09      425
11/19/2016  Pub     250     0.93    0.37      425
11/19/2016  Pub     250     0.69    0.42      425
```

If I was to do Quantile of all Sales for a particular date without looking at only one element of each category I would get something like 550 (which I do not want).

Key thing is I would like the code to be simple, and reasonably fast (as date is quite big). Also interpolation has to be midpoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['Quantile'] = df.Sales.groupby(df.index)
                   .transform(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().quantile())
print (df)
           Category  Sales  Ratio 1  Ratio 2  Quantile
11/19/2016      Bar    300     0.46     0.96       425
11/19/2016      Bar    300     0.56     0.78       425
11/19/2016      Bar    300     0.43     0.96       425
11/19/2016      Bar    300     0.47     0.94       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.92     0.12       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.43     0.74       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.98     0.65       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.76     0.67       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.79     0.80       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.90     0.91       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.89     0.31       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.69     0.99       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.07     0.18       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.75     0.59       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.07     0.64       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.14     0.42       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.30     0.67       425
11/19/2016      Pub    250     0.64     0.09       425
11/19/2016      Pub    250     0.93     0.37       425
11/19/2016      Pub    250     0.69     0.42       425
```

---

```
df['Quantile'] = df.Sales.groupby(df.index)
                   .transform(lambda x: np.percentile(x.unique(), 50))
print (df)
           Category  Sales  Ratio 1  Ratio 2  Quantile
11/19/2016      Bar    300     0.46     0.96       425
11/19/2016      Bar    300     0.56     0.78       425
11/19/2016      Bar    300     0.43     0.96       425
11/19/2016      Bar    300     0.47     0.94       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.92     0.12       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.43     0.74       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.98     0.65       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.76     0.67       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.79     0.80       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.90     0.91       425
11/19/2016   Casino    550     0.89     0.31       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.69     0.99       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.07     0.18       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.75     0.59       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.07     0.64       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.14     0.42       425
11/19/2016     Cafe    700     0.30     0.67       425
11/19/2016      Pub    250     0.64     0.09       425
11/19/2016      Pub    250     0.93     0.37       425
11/19/2016      Pub    250     0.69     0.42       425
```

Comment: Is there a way to add argument to only drop duplicates of category for a particular date? As there might be categories which have same sales value? Ie quantile only one sales value for each category for each date?

Comment: Can you change sample for your requirements? Do you need `filter first` like `df1 = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Category','Sales']) & (df.index.isin(['11-19-2016','11-20-2016']))]` and then apply quantile?